# TreeView state images disappear

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gdi+

There is .NET 4.0 WinForms application.
OS is Windwos 7 x64.

Some form contains *TreeView* and *ImageList*.
(System.Windows.Forms.TreeView)
(System.Windows.Forms.ImageList)

*ImageList* bound to *TreeView* as "ImageList" and "StateImageList".
*ImageList* contains 18 pictures.

State images controlled in program by changing "StateImageIndex" of nodes.

- -1 - no picture
- 1 - checked
- 2 - unchecked

All works well, but sometimes state images disappear.

[Example (screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSVwu.png)

The main problem that i can't reproduce bug conditions.
The bug occurs very rarely.
All images in *ImageList* and "StateImageIndices" are valid at the moment of bug.

"Application.EnableVisualStyles()" called before *ImageList* initialization.

My research at an impasse.
I will be grateful for any prompts and ideas.

Comment: Can you create an [MCVE] that reproduces the issue and [edit] that in your question?

Comment: Thanks for participating. Unfortunately, not. I can't even reproduce a bug in original application. Some application users reported about this bug. Similar error occurred only once on my computer.

Comment: Does your imagelist have an image at index 0 ?

Comment: Yes. ImageList have 18 pictures (index from 0 to 17).